# Listing inbox,outbox,calendars,journal e.t.c. from nsf file (eg: mail/usermail.nsf) using C#

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

I am working on a application where I have to list all user mail NSF file in tree view.
Currently I can list all NSF files.

Next step for me is to list(fetch) in-box,outbox,calenders,journal e.t.c. from NSF file 
(e g: mail/user-mail.NSF).using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes provides a COM interface that would allow you to get to this stuff.  The object model is based around LotusScript but that should still be fine for you.

Create a Notes.NotesSession object and run from there.  [Start here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.designer85.doc/DOC/H_USING_NOTES_CLASSES_IN_VISUAL_BASIC.html) and have a look at the examples link at the bottom of the page.  Of particular interest to you should be:

- Notes.NotesSession.getDatabase()
- Notes.NotesDatabase.open()
- Notes.NotesDatabase.views
- Notes.NotesDatabase.getView()

Online help for all the COM classes [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.designer85.doc/DOC/H_LOTUSSCRIPT_NOTES_CLASSES.html) (Notes 8.5)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gutgames.com/post/Exporting-Documents-from-TeamroomNSF-files-using-C.aspx

This will help you to extract documents from .nsf files